# Cross-reference data from two different JS files

Tags: javascript, import, export, bundler, rollup

In `main.js` I declare a canvas context variable `c`.

```
import { Boid } from './boid';

const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const c = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

In `boid.js` I define a `Boid` class which performs methods on the `c` object from `main.js`

```
export class Boid {
  constructor(pos, vel, accel) {
    this.pos = pos
    this.vel = vel
    this.accel = accel;
  }
  draw() {
    c.beginPath();
  }
}
```

When I view run the site in chrome, console logs

```
boid.js:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: c is not defined
    at e.draw (boid.js:8)
    at t (main.js:23)
    at main.js:29
    at main.js:29
```

Clearly the modularization is not working properly. My question is how I can use variables from `boid.js` in `main.js` and use variables from `main.js` from `boid.js`, preferably without having to import/export in both of them each.

I am using Rollup as a bundler and am therefore only linking one minified js file in index.html, so linking boid.js above main.js is not an option.

You can view my repo yourself at https://github.com/michaelmoreno/boids-algorithm

Comment: you should pass `c` as constructor parameter

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
   window.c = canvas.getContext('2d')
```

then:

```
   window.c.beginPath()
```